# Passing a string to a variable name in lapply

Tags: r, string, lapply

I have duplicate code which I want to reduce:

```
table(all_data$livebirth)  
table(all_data$miscarriage_early)
table(all_data$live_birth) 
table(all_data$alive_baby_28days) 
table(all_data$preg_size)
```

It sounds like lapply is the most efficient way to do this. So I tried the following:

```
case_type=list("livebirth", "misscarriage_early", "live_birth", "alive_baby_28days", "preg_size")
lapply(case_type, function(x) {table(paste0("all_data$", x))})
```

But it just returns:

> [[1]]
>
> all_data$livebirth
> 1
> etc

How do I need to format table() within lapply so that it functions the same as the original code?

edit: I found this workaround, but I am still interested in how I could have achieved it by passing an argument within lapply.

```
lapply(subset(all_data, select = c(livebirth, live_birth, alive_baby_28days, preg_size, miscarriage_early )), table)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on using `lapply`, then the following will do the trick. (I don't have your data, so I will use the `mtcars` data.

```
case_type = colnames(mtcars) # or whichever strings you would like to pass
m1 <- lapply(case_type, function(x) {table(mtcars[[x]])})
```

Another way of performing this would be to use the `tidyverse` package and all its niche functions. If you have not, I can only recommend you to take a look at it. Personally I've grown to appreciate it.

```
library(tidyverse)
m2 <- case_type %>% map( ~table(mtcars[[.]]))
identical(m1, m2)
#> [1] TRUE
```